# Why am I getting in expected T_variable?

Tags: php, variables

```
<?php
         $date = new datetime;
        echo $date->format('m-d-y');
 ?>
```

Can someone see something I can't? I keep getting unexpected $date on the 2 line. (I'm very new when it comes to php. Any help appreciated.)

Comment: This code is fine.

Comment: Unless there is maybe some hidden character somewhere before `$date`

Answer (score 0):

When using the Datetime class you need to instantiate your object using `$date = new DateTime();` and then to display the date use `echo $date->format('Y-m-d');` to display the date on the page (Y-m-d just being a stand in for the date format got need).

**Code**

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score -1):

check the case of your = new datetime. I think it should be

```
 $date = new DateTime();
```

reference

[DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo date_format($date,"m-d-y");
?>
```

Well you can use this. PHP **date_format** function.